# How to detect if a chrome extension exists or not

Tags: python, chrome-web-store

I have a list of chrome extension urls from which I have to make a list of those extensions that do not exist (404) . Currently I am scraping the pages and detecting it, but I was wondering if there was some other way to do it?

So far I have written a python code to scrape the link and detect 404.
My code:-

```
import requests

html= requests.get("<<chrome extension link comes here>>")
html_code = html.text

if ('''code unique to the 404 page of google''' in html_code):    
    print('404 positive')
else:
    print('404 negative')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the response status, try the method `status_code` in requests.

```
link = _your_link_
r = requests.get(link)
r.status_code
```

A 4xx status would indicate an error.

Refer the documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).